# Encoding coordinates to binary and compression

Tags: java, encoding, binary, coordinates

I have been doing research on how to encode coordinates like `24.801044` `120.993085` to binary so that I can send a binary message through a phone and then decode it on another. Problem is that if I do it symbol by symbol then I need almost 80 bits. I also thought about encoding the complete string and then cut it once it is sent.

How to implemenent this better?

Comment: Please share your research / coding effort to date.

Comment: Why don't you send them as double values (IEEE 754 format, the standard in Java - 64 bits) . Where does your number of 80 bits come from? Why is 80 bits a problem? What do you mean with "encode the complete string and then cut it"?

Comment: Oh no, 80 bits! If they're stuck on a phone from 1992, they might have to wait almost a hundredth of a second! *gasps*

Comment: i would recommend encoding using a float per number. This means 2 x 32 bits for the complete coordinate. Come on and tell us the whole story to motivate us supporting a cool project :)

Comment: Isn't this what [WKB](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/WKBWriter.html) (also see [spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/99-049.Pdf), page 3-24) is supposed to achieve? Any reasons not to use it?

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answers. The project is about a mother who wants to communicate with her child but both of them cannot send their location through messages or use internet, so we looked for different ways to send the location, first by getting the location on the phone and then encoding it into binary format... after that we would send it through missing calls automatically. We are not working on the app right now, but want to find a way to encode the location into binary that reduces the number of bits needed to the minimum and then decode the original location :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `float` precision is enough for you, you can use `floatToRawIntBits` to pack both numbers into 64bit long value:

```
float x = 24.801044f;
float y = 120.993085f;
System.out.println("Input: "+x+"; "+y);
// Encode
long data = (((long)Float.floatToRawIntBits(x)) << 32) | Float.floatToRawIntBits(y);
// Now send the data to another phone
// Decode
float resX = Float.intBitsToFloat((int)(data >>> 32));
float resY = Float.intBitsToFloat((int)data);
System.out.println("Result: "+resX+"; "+resY);
```

Output:

```
Input: 24.801044; 120.99309
Result: 24.801044; 120.99309
```

Alternatively you can renormalize the numbers if you know in advance that your coordinates do not exceed some value (like `360`):

```
double x = 24.801044;
double y = 120.993085;
System.out.println("Input: "+x+"; "+y);
// Encode
long data = (Math.round(x * 1e6) << 32) | Math.round(y * 1e6);
// Now send the data to another phone
// Decode
double resX = (data >>> 32)/1e6;
double resY = ((int)data)/1e6;
System.out.println("Input: "+resX+"; "+resY);
```

Output:

```
Input: 24.801044; 120.993085
Result: 24.801044; 120.993085
```

This way you will get better precision

Comment: Thanks Tagir Valeev. I tried and it works really well :) It helped me a lot!